# Which is a better way to query in Django (Raw query vs ORM)?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I am using MySQL, I have two schemas and I have to perform a **join over multiple schemas**, which as you might know is **not supported** with the Django ORM.

So, this is most simplified SQL query for this scenario

```
SELECT * FROM db1.a AS a
JOIN db2.b AS b 
ON b.some_id = a.id
WHERE a.name = 'localhost'
```

**DJANGO ORM**

Now, if I use Django ORM, I will have to do something like

```
a_obj = ModelA.objects.filter(name='localhost')
ModelB.objects.filter(some_id__in=a_obj)
```

**DJANGO RAW SQL / CONNECTION**

```
from django.db import connection

sql = 'SELECT * FROM db1.a AS a
       JOIN db2.b AS b 
       ON b.some_id = a.id
       WHERE a.name = %s'
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
      cursor.execute(sql, ['localhost'])
      row = cursor.fetchall()
except Exception as e:
      cursor.close
```

Now, I understand that both of them are going to give me the required result. But, why use one over the other? From what I see, the Django ORM will have to hit the database twice to get the required info, while the raw query can get it with a single hit, here in my opinion the raw query wins. Again, the raw query prevents from sql injection attacks by using parameterised query, which escapes the variable, thus preventing the attack.

A lot of people have suggested using Django ORM, over the raw query, but, in these scenarios, I don't see Django ORM doing any better than Raw query, it not worse.

So, which one should I use, keeping in mind database performance and security? And Why?

Answer (score 9):

Here's my generic, perhaps unpopular, opinion on ORM vs RAW SQL in Django.

In short, it depends.

The ORM is a common conversion point among the majority of developers who work with Django. Most Django developers are going to have a comfort level with the Django orm. Most tutorials, plugins, and examples leverage the orm to interface with the database. I've even seen some junior devs who don't even know SQL queries and only know how to use the ORM.

RAW SQL will be more efficient in a lot of cases, however you then bypass the abstraction benefits the ORM provides.

If you truly care about optimizing then RAW SQL will be inevitable, but if you care more about (depending on the team) consistency and leveraging the abstraction then stick with the ORM.

My personal strategy is to stick with the ORM as much as I can even in cases when it's less efficient. I don't use Django much anymore, but when I do use Django I'm using it solely to use its batteries, packages, plugins, and extensions to increase developer efficiency. If I really cared about performance and optimization I wouldn't be using Django in the first place.

Comment: When you say abstraction benefits, what exactly do u mean in layman's term? Sorry, I am a bit new to Django.

Comment: If you write raw sql you won't be accessing the data through the ORM interface (call signitures). This will bind your functions to the DB that you've chosen to run and you'll no longer be able to switch your DB from say Postgres to SQLite without having to update your RAW queries.

Comment: Which means, suppose, I have a master slave database architecture. Normally Django models would handle the read from slave, insert into master thing. But, the raw queries will not handle this, and we have to modify the raw query to do so?